# React make an async call on data after retrieving it from the state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, use-effect, infinite-loop

I need to make an async call after I get some data from a custom hook.  My problem is that when I do it causes an infinite loop.

```
export function useFarmInfo(): {
  [chainId in ChainId]: StakingBasic[];
} {
  return {
    [ChainId.MATIC]: Object.values(useDefaultFarmList()[ChainId.MATIC]),
    [ChainId.MUMBAI]: [],
  };
}

// hook to grab state from the state
const lpFarms = useFarmInfo();
const dualFarms = useDualFarmInfo();

//Memoize the pairs
const pairLists = useMemo(() => {
  const stakingPairLists = lpFarms[chainIdOrDefault].map((item) => item.pair);
  const dualPairLists = dualFarms[chainIdOrDefault].map((item) => item.pair);
  return stakingPairLists.concat(dualPairLists);
}, [chainIdOrDefault, lpFarms, dualFarms]);

//Grab the bulk data results from the web
useEffect(() => {
  getBulkPairData(pairLists).then((data) => setBulkPairs(data));
}, [pairLists]);
```

I think whats happening is that when I set the state it re-renders which causes hook to grab the farms from the state to be reset, and it creates an infinite loop.

I tried to move the `getBulkPairData` into the memoized function, but that's not meant to handle promises.

How do I properly make an `async` call after retrieving data from my hooks?

Comment: Your use effect has a dependency on pairLsts which presumably gets set by `setBulkpairs` which is causing the effect to fire again. Is your intent to fire it once? Remove the depdency. Fetch once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I can give you a solution to your problem, but I can give you some hints on how to find out the cause:

First you can find out if the useEffect hook gets triggered too often because its dependency changes too often, or if the components that contains your code gets re-mounted over and over again:

Remove the dependency of your `useEffect` hook and see if it still gets triggered too often. If so, your problem lies outside of your component.

If not, find out if the dependencies of your `useMemo` hook change unexpectedly:

```js
useEffect(()=>console.log("chainIdOrDefault changed"), [chainIdOrDefault]);
useEffect(()=>console.log("lpFarms changed"), [lpFarms]);
useEffect(()=>console.log("dualFarms changed"), [dualFarms]);
```

I assume, this is the most likely reason - maybe `useFarmInfo` or `useDualFarmInfo` create new objects on each render (even if these objects contain the same data on each render, they might not be identical). If so, either change these hooks and add some memoization (if you have access to your code) or narrow down the dependencies of your `pairLists`:

```js
const pairLists = useMemo(() => {
  const stakingPairLists = lpFarms[chainIdOrDefault].map((item) => item.pair);
  const dualPairLists = dualFarms[chainIdOrDefault].map((item) => item.pair);
  return stakingPairLists.concat(dualPairLists);
}, [lpFarms[chainIdOrDefault], dualFarms[chainIdOrDefault]]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated the example. I'd upvote this (but I need 15 reputation to even upvote)

Comment: Yeah you we're right,  I didn't realize that if I used Object.Values each time it would consider this a new object since hypothetically the hash code should be the same!